# Elegant solution to VS code C/C++ include path for both intelliSense and building project

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

How to create `task.json` and `launch.json` for building and debugging a C/C++ project, that parameters can be loaded automatically from `c_cpp_configuration.json`?
(parameters such as include path, compiler path)

Enviroments:

> windows 10.0.19041
> VS Code 1.52.1
> VS Code extension: ms-vscode.cpptools 1.2.2

Lets say I have the following file structure:

```
./
 |
 |--- .vscode/
 |
 |--- inc/
 |     |--- header1.h
 |     |--- header2.h
 |
 |--- src/
 |     |--- implementation1.c
 |     |--- implementation2.c
 |
 |--- main.c
```

And I have the include path set in global `settings.json`:

```json
"C_Cpp.default.includePath": ["${workspaceFolder}/inc"],
```

The intelliSense works fine. I can find the definition of headers from the reference in `main.c`.
And I know I can have the project built successfully without vs code:

```
gcc -g .\*.c .\src\*.c -I .\inc
```

So, if I want to build this project with vs code, I have to set `task.json` like this:

```json
...
      "args": [
        "-g",
        "${workspaceFolder}\\*.c", "${workspaceFolder}\\src\\*.c",
        "-I", "${workspaceFolder}\\inc",
        "-o", "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
      ]
...
```

For both intelliSense and project build working, I have to configure the paths at `settings.json`(`c_cpp_configuration.json`) and `task.json`.
What I want is a elegant solution that I only have to set the include paths once for both intelliSense and project build working. Is it possible? It would be awesome if I can solve this without extra extensions. But you have a extension that can replace the `ms-vscode.cpptools` and do the trick, that would also be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I do: uninstall Microsoft's C/C++ extension and replace it with [Clangd](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=llvm-vs-code-extensions.vscode-clangd) for code completion and [Native Debug](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=webfreak.debug) for debugging. I had better experience with those two, including easier configuration.

Clangd is configured by a single file called [`compile_commands.json`](https://clangd.llvm.org/installation#project-setup), which is just a list of compiler flags for each source file.

Then, start using a proper build system. CMake, for example, can generate this file out of the box. For Make, [there's a tool](https://github.com/rizsotto/Bear) to generate it. In a pinch, you can write it yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will give it a try. Make and CMake are definitely the ones I have to learn sooner or later. However, I am still looking for a solution with `ms-vscode.cpptools`. If there is no new answer for a while, this answer will be accepted.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you, go with this extension:

> **CPH Judge**

As it will clear all the problems of the debugger and all u can input direct values in input and get output!!

Pros:

> 1. It has a test case option as we have in online exams, so you can type a and to the test case given in the question and check your answer, accordingly!

> 2. You can run multiple test cases also!!