# VScode c/c++ addon gives error to "typedef unsigned _ExtInt(FPBITS) fp_t;" for clang++-11 version

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense, clang++

So, I have this ubuntu20.04 on wsl with vscode running on it.
I installed 3 compilers "gcc" "clang" "clang-11".
I kind wanna use this _ExtInt() feature which only exists in clang++-11 to write some code in vscode.

Although this Microsoft product addon c/c++ keeping highlight a line

```
#define FPBITS 704

typedef unsigned _ExtInt(FPBITS) fp_t;
```

**expected a type specifier** at FPBITS and **expected a ';'** at fp_t

I've tried configuration below for c_cpp_properties.json bt it doesn't work. Anybody any help plz?

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang++-11",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++11",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: Is it a VSC-only error? Does it compile otherwise?

Comment: it seems a c/c++ extension mis-setting for me. Thought I couldn't come up with any solution...
The code complies well and exec well.
just the this c/c++ intellisence dosent make sence.

Comment: sry I accidently replied while I was writing.
I edit my relply. plz check it out.

Comment: Ah, ok. My guess is that Microsoft's intellisense just doesn't know about this Clang feature. You could replace it with a [clang-based autocompletion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67972613/2752075).

Comment: thx, I'll give a try then :)

Comment: It works! thx!! nice day to you!